# how can i extract title and content in it from a list of urls in excel and save it to .txt file?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp, data-extraction

For each of the articles, given in the input.xlsx file, extract the article text and save the extracted article in a text file with URL_ID as its file name.
While extracting text, please make sure your program extracts only the article title and the article text. It should not extract the website header, footer, or anything other than the article text.

```
i tried this code..

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Smart-Watches/178893/bn_152365'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

Title = [title.text for name in soup.find_all('a', 
class_='title')]
Description= [Description.text for desc in soup.find_all('p', 
class_='description')]

for i in range(len(Title)):
print(Title[i])
print(Description[i])    
print()
def Save_to_file():
f = open('URL_ID.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
for i in range(len(Title)):
    f.write(Title[i] + "\n")
    f.write(Description[i] + "\n")
f.close()
```

.....

NO errors and no output

....

Comment: You mentioned that from iterating the urls from the excel up till getting the text_content has no issues? Now you are left with saving to a .txt file?

Comment: if you print(text_content) and that's the content you want, to save it to a txt file, just use python function to open and write the file >> https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply that is fine but i am getting error in the above code the which extracts data from urls

Comment: Please edit your title and question to state the error you receive. Also provide us with the url or a html sample, else we are not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have updated my code sir please refer to it and help me out thank you.

Comment: Your issue is you didn't add in any headers so the requests loads forever. Look at my example code below on how to add headers to your requests.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that ebay blocks the url if you don't give it the headers that it needs. refer to the code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"Accept-Language": "es-ES,es;q=0.9",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Smart-Watches/178893/bn_152365'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

You need to confirm that it is printing. go step by step. So now soup should give you an output like shown below. Previously it would have been empty.
[image]

Then only find for the title and description. Inspect the page to look for the tags and attributes of that element. Yours is not correct so it wouldn't output anything.